Next Js 14 cannot modify cookies outside app folder
I have global layout page where I passed Header component:

/src/app/[locale]/layout.tsx

return (
    <html lang={locale}>
      <head>
        <ThemeModeScript />
      </head>
      <body
        className={twMerge(
          "bg-gray-50 text-black dark:bg-black dark:text-white",
          inter.className,
        )}
      >
        <SessionProvider>
          <Flowbite theme={{ theme: flowbiteTheme }}>
            <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
------------>  <Header locale={locale} />
              <main>{children}</main>
              <Footer />
            </NextIntlClientProvider>
          </Flowbite>
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );

Header file with "use server" directive:

/src/components/Header/index.tsx

"use server";

import SiteIcon from "@/app/favicon.ico";
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth";
import { getCart } from "@/lib/db/cart";
import {
  Navbar,
  NavbarBrand,
  NavbarCollapse,
  NavbarToggle,
  TextInput,
} from "flowbite-react";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { getTranslations } from "next-intl/server";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import PageEntry from "./PageEntry";
import { searchProducts } from "./SearchProducts";
import ShoppingCartButton from "./ShoppingCartButton";
import UserMenuAvatar from "./UserMenuAvatar";

export type NavLinks = NavLink[];
export type NavLink = { active: boolean; title: string; href: string };

type Props = {
  locale: string;
};

export default async function Header({ locale }: Readonly<Props>) {
--------->  const cart = await getCart();

...

Finally, shared library file "cart":

/src/lib/db/cart.ts

import { Cart, CartItem, Prisma } from "@prisma/client";
import { deleteCookie, getCookie, setCookie } from "cookies-next";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { authOptions } from "../auth";
import { Dimensions } from "../shared";
import { prisma } from "./prisma";

const cartId = "localCartId";

const include = { items: { include: { product: true } } };

export type CartWithProducts = Prisma.CartGetPayload<{
  include: typeof include;
}>;

export type CartItemWithProduct = Prisma.CartItemGetPayload<{andand
  include: { product: true };
}>;

export type ShoppingCart = CartWithProducts & {
  dimension: string;
  subtotal: number;
};

export async function getCart(): Promise<ShoppingCart> {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  let cart: CartWithProducts | null = null;

  if (session) {
    cart = await prisma.cart.findFirst({
      where: { userId: session.user.id },
      include,
    });
  } else {
    const localCartId = getCookie(cartId);
    cart = localCartId
      ? await prisma.cart.findUnique({
          where: { id: localCartId },
          include,
        })
      : null;
  }

  if (cart == null) {
    return createCart();
  }

  return {
    ...cart,
    dimension: cart.items[0]?.dimension ?? Dimensions["16x20"],
    subtotal: cart.items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.product.price, 0),
  };
}

export async function createCart(): Promise<ShoppingCart> {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  let newCart: Cart;

  if (session) {
    newCart = await prisma.cart.create({ data: { userId: session.user.id } });
  } else {
    newCart = await prisma.cart.create({ data: {} });

---------->  setCookie(cartId, newCart.id, { cookies });
  }

  return { ...newCart, items: [], dimension: "16x9", subtotal: 0 };
}

...

Code giving error highlighted with huge arrow in all 3 files
setCookie(cartId, newCart.id, { cookies }); function at very bottom of library file, expected to create the cookie, but instead giving the Error:
Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
    at createCart (./src/lib/db/cart.ts:70:64)
    at async Header (./src/components/Header/index.tsx:40:18)

I tried:

swapping "use server" with "use client", deleting this directive.
Created server action like in the docs

// Server Component
export default function Page() {
  // Server Action
  async function create() {
    'use server'
 
    // ...
  }
 
  return (
    // ...
  )
}


put "use server" at the top of createCart function
replaced setCookie(cartId, newCart.id, { cookies }); from "cookies-next" package with normal cookies().set(cartId, newCart.id) from "next/headers"
set cookies from /src/components/Header/index.tsx

nothing works...
GitHub repository:
https://github.com/KovalchukDanil0/paint-my-pet
Do you guys have known how to fix this issue or maybe have similar situation with working solution?
Thanks for the help)
